# Regex only match multiline Comments

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a Regular Expression that matches all multiline comments within a String. The problem is, i'm not allowed to match single line comments in the same format.

**Match:**

```
/* This 
is a 
multiline 
comment 
*/
```

**No Match:**

```
/* This is a single line comment */
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Match any multiline comment and then check if it contains a newline.

Comment: Fixed some errors in the answer. If you already checked it, try again, please.

Comment: Perfect it works. I was trying to clean up my Code before I run a JUnit Test. In order to make sure the Test works properly I had to get rid of all multiline Comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that (with addidional corrections depending on the language you are using):

```
\/\*((?!\*\/)[^\r\n])*[\r\n]((?!\*\/)[\s\S\r\n])*\*\/
```

Test:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('textarea').value.match(/\/\*((?!\*\/)[^\r\n])*[\r\n]((?!\*\/)[\s\S\r\n])*\*\//g).join("\n\n"))
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea>Match: /* This 
is a 
multiline 
comment 
*/

No Match: /* This is a single line comment */

Match: /* 
This is a multiline ** comment */

No Match: /* This is a single line comment */

Match: /* This is a multiline ** comment 
*/</textarea>
```